# Auto execution of "validate metadata" in Impala

Tags: hive, cloudera, tableau-api, impala

I have Tableau connected to Cloudera Impala data. The table I am reading from Metastore keeps on updating so, when I want the viz to update (pressing F5) I have to go to Impala in Cloudera and execute "INVALIDATE METADATA" before refreshing the viz. I know this can be done using the connection to Hive Server 2, but it takes a long time to execute the query. My question is there anyway to automatically execute "validate metadata" and "Refresh" queries in Impala Cloudera?

Thanks,

Amr

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Impala does not offer a mechanism to automatically update metadata yet. We are working on this for the future, though we haven't committed such functionality to a particular release yet.

In the meantime, there may be some things you can do to make this easier. Firstly, how is the table being updated? Are there new data files? If so, you can run REFRESH which is faster. Also, be sure to only INVALIDATE/REFRESH the specific table, e.g. `REFRESH my_table`. See the documentation for `[INVALIDATE METADATA][1]` and [REFRESH](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-2-x/topics/impala_refresh.html) for more information.

Is there some ETL process in the background? Some users modify their workflow to issue a REFRESH command to impala after updating a table, e.g.
in a script adding `impala-shell -i <impalad-host> -q "REFRESH my_table"`

Comment: The data is being ingested by Flume and Hive is creating the table then Tableau creates a viz. So. I want the viz. to be updated using Impala as it is much faster than Hive.

Comment: Can you create the table in Impala? Then you won't need to update the metadata explicitly.

Comment: I did try that in impala I used:
 
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ImpData(
  DatetimeL TIMESTAMP,
  V1 FLOAT,
  V2 FLOAT,
  V3 FLOAT
  ) 
  row format delimited fields terminated by','
  LOCATION '/user/data/';

Comment: I think any updating/creating tables in Impala requires to execute Invalidate/Refresh

Comment: If you issue the CREATE TABLE and then the subsequent queries on the same node it shouldn't be necessary because that impalad already knows about the metadata change. What was the behavior you observed?